# collection_select using value from nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select field with a collection of all `Address`. I want to show something like `"address.name / country.name"` as value.

```
= item.collection_select :address_id, Address.all, :id, :name
```

Currently in this sample, I'm only showing `address.name` attribute. How can I nest other values here and how can I call a value from a nested association? (`address.country.name`). ?

I got it working by doing something like this. Just wondering if there is something better.

```
%select{name: "user[address_id]"}
  - Address.all.each do |address|
    %option{value: address.id}
      = address.name
      = address.country.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own method on the Address model that will return a nice name for the collection select:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name_with_country
    str = self.name
    str += " #{self.country.name}" if self.country.present?
    str
  end
```

And use it in the collection_select:

```
= item.collection_select :address_id, Address.all, :id, :name_with_country
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
= item.collection_select :country_id, Address.all, :id, :full_address
```

Than add a method to your model :

```
def full_address
   full_address = name
   full_address += " / #{country.name}" if country.present?
   full_address
 end
```

Comment: But this will only print country name. What if the value is composed of more than one attribute?

Comment: You should feel bad about copy-past my answer with just variable's name changed.

Comment: Also your full_address method will return exactly "name/ " if there is no country selected ...

Comment: But I answered earlier than you. What he asked, After that he added comment on my answer. and than you add solution for that, So you should feel about that.

Comment: Clicking on the "edited X mins ago" proves that you changed your wrong answer to a copy of mine.